# reactjs return to same segment of page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a long page built in reactjs (SPA). It has many links. When user scrolls down and clicks one of these links, new page gets rendered.

All is good but when users hits back button (browser), previous long page gets re-rendered and goes back to top.

Is there any easy solution to make sure used goes to exactly same segment of page where he last clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would register a click event on each link and preventDefault behavior or use other elements like a span with a click event.
after this you need to store the scrollhight, like [here](http://blog.vjeux.com/2013/javascript/scroll-position-with-react.html)

```
myclick: function() {
  var node = this.getDOMNode();
  node.scrollTop = node.scrollHeight;
  //navigate to your new site , update location
},
```

store your `scrollTop` in a state or [local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) and when the user hits the back button, you need to check if scrollTop is set and update the `scrollposition` back to this node.

May have a look at [this](http://blog.grayghostvisuals.com/js/detecting-scroll-position/)  or [this](http://mrcoles.com/blog/scroll-sneak-maintain-position-between-page-loads/). But i think there is no easy solution.

Maybe some of this links are helpful: [Link 1](https://github.com/sakabako/scrollMonitor) , [Link 2](https://github.com/jeroencoumans/react-scroll-components)

[React-Router](https://rackt.github.io/react-router/#ImitateBrowserBehavior)

Comment: +1 for answer. This might not be useful for me because my page is dynamic. User rendering content on click. I need to find out which link user clicked before navigating away from page. I'll store that link and restore the site. Is it possible get that link?

Comment: @JS-JMS-WEB maybe give each link a unique id (ancor) and scroll to this id. like domain/yoursite#hash like this : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.createclass , as long your id is unique the content can be dynamic

Comment: If I persist page state by re-rendering same amount of components. React works by default! But it doesn't work in firefox.